# "W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater" error in Android Studio log

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

Working on a [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) app, iOS & Android. iOS is working fine, and android *seems* to be too. However upon checking the log in Android Studio, I see the following error:

```
08-16 13:26:01.471 8881-8898/com.APP_NAME D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                              [ 08-16 13:26:01.570  8881: 8881 D/         ]
                                                              HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaa3fb100, tid 8881
08-16 13:26:01.656 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTRenderableViewManager
08-16 13:26:01.658 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTGroupShadowNode
08-16 13:26:01.661 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTShapeShadowNode
08-16 13:26:01.663 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTTextShadowNode
08-16 13:26:01.674 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTSurfaceViewManager
08-16 13:26:01.676 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTSurfaceViewShadowNode
08-16 13:26:01.680 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.picker.ReactDialogPickerManager
08-16 13:26:01.681 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode
08-16 13:26:01.682 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayoutManager
08-16 13:26:01.682 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.picker.ReactDropdownPickerManager
08-16 13:26:01.683 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactHorizontalScrollViewManager
08-16 13:26:01.683 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.image.ReactImageManager
08-16 13:26:01.709 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.modal.ReactModalHostManager
08-16 13:26:01.718 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.modal.ModalHostShadowNode
08-16 13:26:01.720 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ReactProgressBarViewManager
08-16 13:26:01.725 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ProgressBarShadowNode
08-16 13:26:01.725 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactRawTextManager
08-16 13:26:01.726 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextShadowNode
08-16 13:26:01.727 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactScrollViewManager
08-16 13:26:01.728 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.slider.ReactSliderManager
08-16 13:26:01.729 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.slider.ReactSliderManager$ReactSliderShadowNode
08-16 13:26:01.730 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager
08-16 13:26:01.741 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager$ReactSwitchShadowNode
08-16 13:26:01.741 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.frescosupport.FrescoBasedReactTextInlineImageViewManager
08-16 13:26:01.741 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.frescosupport.FrescoBasedReactTextInlineImageShadowNode
08-16 13:26:01.742 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactTextInputManager
08-16 13:26:01.743 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactTextInputShadowNode
08-16 13:26:01.743 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextViewManager
08-16 13:26:01.743 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.toolbar.ReactToolbarManager
08-16 13:26:01.753 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewManager
08-16 13:26:01.755 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.viewpager.ReactViewPagerManager
08-16 13:26:01.759 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactVirtualTextViewManager
08-16 13:26:01.759 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.webview.ReactWebViewManager
08-16 13:26:01.761 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.recyclerview.RecyclerViewBackedScrollViewManager
08-16 13:26:01.771 8881-8895/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.swiperefresh.SwipeRefreshLayoutManager

                                                                                  [ 08-16 13:26:01.807  8881: 8898 D/         ]
                                                                                  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaa3fb220, tid 8898
08-16 13:26:01.822 8881-8898/com.APP_NAME I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-16 13:26:01.935 8881-8881/com.APP_NAME W/unknown:React: Unable to dispatch keyboard events in JS as the react instance has not been attached
08-16 13:26:02.604 8881-8910/com.APP_NAME I/ReactNativeJS: Running application "APP_NAME" with appParams: {"initialProps":{},"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
08-16 13:26:02.792 8881-8933/com.APP_NAME I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.android.webview version 44.0.2403.119 (code 246011910)
08-16 13:26:02.892 8881-8933/com.APP_NAME W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/app/webview/lib/x86
08-16 13:26:02.914 8881-8933/com.APP_NAME I/LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 11 ms (timestamps 6909-6920)
08-16 13:26:02.915 8881-8933/com.APP_NAME I/LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
08-16 13:26:02.930 8881-8933/com.APP_NAME W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
08-16 13:27:57.070 8881-8898/com.APP_NAME E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa05caf80
08-16 13:27:57.521 8881-10447/com.APP_NAME I/ReactNativeJS: Running application "APP_NAME" with appParams: {"initialProps":{},"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
08-16 13:27:59.543 8881-8891/com.APP_NAME I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 18907(816KB) AllocSpace objects, 4(80KB) LOS objects, 13% free, 6MB/7MB, paused 12.412ms total 46.669ms
08-16 13:35:46.465 8881-8887/com.APP_NAME W/art: Suspending all threads took: 20.834ms
08-16 13:36:00.940 8881-8887/com.APP_NAME W/art: Suspending all threads took: 34.757ms
08-16 13:36:06.015 8881-8887/com.APP_NAME W/art: Suspending all threads took: 11.770ms
08-16 13:38:22.698 8881-8887/com.APP_NAME W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10.460ms
08-16 13:41:30.102 8881-8887/com.APP_NAME W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.623ms
```

Have looked into it, and found: [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5304) & [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7587) but they're from older versions of RN - we're on `0.29.2`.

(*APP_NAME* is replacing the app name - duh - in this snippet)

Comment: What was the issue?